# Mondrian MDX Number of elements that match a condition

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I'm trying to get the number of facts that match a condition.

My desired output: the number of ratings that are bigger than 3.
What I actually get: the total number of user ratings in case that the average of the ratings is over 3.

This is my query:

```
With Member [Measures].[Number of possitive ratings] as
  IIF(
      [Measures].[User Rating] > 3,
      [Measures].[Number of Users Rating],
      0)
SELECT NON EMPTY
[Measures].[Number of possitive ratings] ON COLUMNS,
[Movie Year].[All Years] ON ROWS
FROM
    [Rating]
```

When I replace [Measures].[Number of Users Rating] for 1, then I get 1 in case the average is over 3.
I don't like the idea of creating a new measure in the cube just for this.